# How to get back text in html format by using something like URLDecode

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am passing value of text-area in a.cfm in variable of GetXmlHttpObject to b.cfm page and displaying the value in a . How can I get exact formatting of the text I entered in text-area of a.cfm page into div of b.cfm page.

```
a.cfm
    <textarea name="sum1#i#" id="sum1#i#" html="yes" cols="98" rows="5"></textarea> [my text area]
    url=url+"?dept="+iden+"&desc="+encodeURIComponent(desc); [desc: value of text area]

b.cfm
    <cfoutput>
    <div style="border:1px solid">#URLDecode(desc)#</div>   
    </cfoutput>
```

Like I am sending value as 'hellothere'
encodeURIComponent: 'hello%0Athere'

but its appearing as 'hello there' [in one line]
I want it to be in: 'hello `<break-line>` there' [in two different lines, means in the same format as it was in text-area]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<pre></pre>` tags will preserve spaces and newlines.

```
<cfoutput>
    <div style="border:1px solid"> <pre>#URLDecode(desc)#</pre> </div>   
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You'll want to be extremely careful, as doing this could open your site up for XSS and possibly other security attacks. (An attacker could send someone to `b.cfm?desc=</textarea><script type='text/javascript'>function submitUserPasswordToMySite(){...}; submitUserPasswordToMySite();</script>` and it would have access to local data and be able to send data to an external location that would log it.) As a general rule, never directly render something from the URL on the page without *cleaning* it first. By cleaning, of course, I mean removing potential security threats.

Comment: great work! Ryan, I never thought that the problem was so easy to solve. Thanks